# for loop character printing

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, char, character

***.....................HEY GUYS,I GOT THE ANSWER.PLEASE CHECK OUT AT BOTTOM.....................***

*ThAnKs FoR aLl ThOsE wHo TrYiNg tO hElP mE!*

How to print all the character outside the for-loop that input inside for-loop? It only prints the last character entered in for-loop

> input all 4 names of items and price in **void shop::getdata()**
>
> output of this only prints the name of item that entered last in *void shop::getdata()* for 4 times in **void shop::putdata()**
>
> output of price is correct,it prints orderly.
>
> what's the problem with the name of item?

**Question**:WAP to store pricelist of 5 items & print the largest price as well as the sum of all prices & pricelist also.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

class shop
{
  int i;
  char item[50];
  float price[50];
public:
  void getdata();
  void putdata();
  float sum();
  float lar();
};

void shop::getdata()
{
  for(i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
  {
    cout << "Enter the item name:" << "\n";
    cin >> item;
    cout << "Enter price:" << "\n";
    cin >> price[i];
  }
}

void shop::putdata()
{
  cout << "\t\tPRICE LIST" << "\n";
  cout << "\t\t**********" << "\n";
  cout << "ITEM NAME\t\t\tPRICE" << "\n";
  cout << "*********\t\t\t*****" << "\n";
  for(i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
  {
    cout << item << "\t\t\t\t";
    cout << price[i] << "\n";
  }
}

float shop::sum()
{
  float sum = 0;
  for( i= 0; i <= 4; i++)
  {
    sum = sum + price[i];
  }
  cout << "\t\t\t\tsum is:" << sum << "\n";
  return sum;
}

float shop::lar()
{
  float lar;
  lar = price[0];
  for(i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
  {
    if (price[i] > lar)
      lar = price[i];
  }
  cout << "\t\t\tlargest is:" << lar;
  return lar;
}

void main()
{
  shop x;
  int c;
  clrscr();
  x.getdata();
  do
  {
    cout << "\n\n1.PRICE LIST\n";
    cout << "2.SUM\n";
    cout << "3.LARGEST\n";
    cout << "4.EXIT\n";
    cout << "Enter your choice\n";
    cin >> c;
    switch (c)
    {
    case 1:
      x.putdata();
      break;
    case 2:
      x.sum();
      break;
    case 3:
      x.lar();
      break;
    default:
      cout << "PRESS ANY KEY TO EXIT\n";
      break;
    }
  }
  while(c >= 1 && c <= 3);
  getch();
}
```

***ANSWER***

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

class shop
{
  int i;
  char item[50];
  float price;
  float e[10];
public:
  void getdata();
  void putdata();
  float sum();
  float lar();
};

void shop::getdata()
{
    cout << "Enter the item name:" << "\n";
    cin >> item;
    cout << "Enter price:" << "\n";
    cin >> price;
}

void shop::putdata()
{
    cout << item << "\t\t\t\t";
    cout << price << "\n";
}

float shop::sum()
{
  float sum = 0;
  for( i= 0; i <= 4; i++)
  {
   cout<<"Enter prices"<<"\n";
   cin>>e[i];
    sum = sum + e[i];
  }
  cout << "\t\t\t\tsum is:" << sum << "\n";
  return sum;
}

float shop::lar()
{
  float lar;
  lar = e[0];
  for(i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
  {
    if (e[i] > lar)
      lar = e[i];
  }
  cout << "\t\t\tlargest is:" << lar;
  return lar;
}

void main()
{
  shop x[10];
  int c,i;
  clrscr();
  for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
  x[i].getdata();
  do
  {
    cout << "\n\n1.PRICE LIST\n";
    cout << "2.SUM\n";
    cout << "3.LARGEST\n";
    cout << "4.EXIT\n";
    cout << "Enter your choice\n";
    cin >> c;
    switch (c)
    {
    case 1:
    for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
      x[i].putdata();
      break;
    case 2:
      x[i].sum();
      break;
    case 3:
      x[i].lar();
      break;
    default:
      cout << "PRESS ANY KEY TO EXIT\n";
      break;
    }
  }
  while(c >= 1 && c <= 3);
  getch();
}
```

Comment: @user782885: Come again?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal:yes .iwant to print the whole thing in the loop again.any way???

Comment: I wish I had time to list the things wrong with this code snippet.

Comment: Which `for` loop are you talking about?  You've got several.  You also have failed to indent your code understandably, and it would help if you'd show some sample output you were expecting and what you get instead.  Finally, `void main()` is not valid C++, and "conio.h" is a nonstandard extension that isn't used in any vaguely modern C++ compiler to my knowledge, so I'd suggest you get something more up-to-date.

Comment: @David: And I haven't seen `iostream.h` since pre-1998. And `string.h` is either supposed to be pre-1998 `string`, or `cstring`. Not that he uses either.

Comment: Seriously, I approve of people trying to learn C++, but what you're doing isn't going to teach it to you.  Modern compilers are available for free on all major modern platforms and most of the minor ones, and any book that teaches `void main()` and "conio.h" won't teach you anything like modern C++.

Comment: Your code basically makes no sense. I think you should define the program before you fix the problems in it.

Comment: What's with the obnoxious capitalisation? Bit of professionalism please.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to tell what you're asking (you would do well to indent your code and ask a clearer question), but I think your problem (well, the main one you're referring to!) is how you're handling `item` names.

You've declared your shop to contain an array of 50 `char`s - that is, 50 single characters. Since you have an array of 50 `price`s, you almost certainly wanted an array of 50 *strings*. In basic C, that would be `char *item[50]`, an array of 50 dynamically-allocated char arrays. Since you've tagged this as C++, though, you're better off using a [`string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/).

Comment: @Teni: Frankly, no. As others have pointed out, this is not the only problem with your code. I've shown you what's causing the specific problem you asked about and given you enough information to work out how to fix it. SO is _not_ a place to get others to write your code for you.

Comment: @Teni: no worries, and apologies if I came over harshly. Don't be disheartened about the response to your first question here; listen to some of the advice given in the comments above, improve your understanding, and keep asking questions. You'll soon work out what's useful for learning. :)

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more modern shop would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::ostream;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

class Item {
  string m_name;
  double m_price;

public:
  Item(const string &name, double price)
  : m_name(name), m_price(price) {
  };

  string name() const { return m_name; }
  double price() const { return m_price; }
};

class Shop {
  vector<Item> m_items;

public:
  void readData();
  void writeData() const;
  double getPriceSum() const;
  double getMaxPrice() const;
};

void Shop::readData() {
  for (;;) {
    string name, end_of_line;
    double price;

    cout << "Enter the item name (or nothing to finish input): ";
    getline(cin, name);
    if (name == "") {
      break;
    }

    cout << "Enter the price: ";
    cin >> price;

    // the previous ">>" left the end-of-line in the stream,
    // so read it now.
    getline(cin, end_of_line);

    m_items.push_back(Item(name, price));
  }
}

void Shop::writeData() const {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < m_items.size(); i++) {
    const Item &item = m_items[i];

    cout << item.name() << "\t" << item.price() << "\n";
  }
}

double Shop::getPriceSum() const {
  double sum = 0.0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < m_items.size(); i++) {
    sum += m_items[i].price();
  }
  return sum;
}

double Shop::getMaxPrice() const {
  double max = 0.0; // assume that all prices are positive
  for (size_t i = 0; i < m_items.size(); i++) {
    max = std::max(max, m_items[i].price());
  }
  return max;
}

int main() {
  Shop shop;

  shop.readData();
  shop.writeData();
  cout << "sum: " << shop.getPriceSum() << "\n";
  cout << "max: " << shop.getMaxPrice() << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

It is not perfect C++ style, but still makes the code easy to read.